# Подскажите пожалуйста, как бы реализовали вы

Tags: php

появился вопрос, суть ниже.

Я имею сайт, на котором подключено 5 и более, различных API.

Нужно сделать, так чтобы из 5 заказов, ушло на 5 разных платформ, но, чтобы была возможность к примеру отключить к примеру 2 платформы, и скрипт от этого не пострадал.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как бы это можно реализовать,чтобы не очень сильно шла нагрузка на сервер, и главное - все работало.

Comment: p.s. то есть сделать нормальное распределение..

Comment: Попробуй сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы его можно было понять

Comment: А какая собственно проблема, долго отрабатывается скрипт, падает сервер из-за ошибки и дальше работа прерывается? Может быть множество решений, была бы описана сама проблема )

Comment: Да, запрос долго обрабатывается.. И в случае большой нагрузки, сервер падает..

Comment: Фоново запросы нельзя обрабатывать, к примеру очередь по крону в режиме простоя сервера, нужно прямо сейчас и желательно все, а если отвалились некоторые то не роняя сервер выполнить сколько удалось?

Comment: @РашенБеарsaystohellMonica если человек не может описать вопрос по другому, нужно вытянуть с него эту информацию и попытаться помочь.

Comment: @RifmaMan нет. Лучше пойти заниматься своими делами

Comment: Попробуй переформулировать мой вопрос.
Нужно сделать распределение заказов между разными API-платформами.
То есть к примеру, я имею 5 разных API-платформ, между которыми нужно распределить заказы.
Я имею алгоритм, но он во-первых ложится из-за нагрузки, а во-вторых не могу в нем сделать такую вещь, как возможность включения/отключения, той или иной платформы.

Comment: **То есть подскажите пожалуйста, как бы реализовать такую систему:**
Мы имеем сайт, на котором есть форма заказа, после введение пользователем информации идет переброска на скрипт-обработчика, далее скрипт должен распределять между 5 платформами эти заказы, то есть 1 заказ, на одну платформу и тд.. Но как сделать возможность отключение к примеру нескольких платформ(допустим 3ех), и вместо 5 платформ распределить трафик между 2умя, не переписывая скрипт.

Спасибо, за помощь.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема после отправки данных с формы скажем в "контроллер" (который распределяет и смотрит скольким интерфейсам нужно передавать задачи на исполнения), также не передать и параметр конкретных API в виде чекбоксов который должны отработать по этим данным?

Comment: проблема в том, как определить скрипту, какая платформа следующая..

Comment: Вообще простая отправка заказа на какую-то апишку не должна никак ушатывать сервак. Сейчас у любого более менее серьезного магазина куча интеграций со складами, СRM и т.д. и нагрузка на сервер минимальна. Начни с этого.

Comment: Но ведь мы не знаем что у вас там "за бугром" творится, как сообщество может помочь если нет конкретики, вы можете получать ответ, можете использовать try...catch можно еще что нибудь придумать, но не видя логики, примерного кода, люди вам не смогут помочь!

Comment: @Pantabi запиши в базу на какую последнюю отправлял

Comment: Конфиг активных/неактивных апи можно положить в бд, а запросы к этим апи я бы реализовал через очередь. Если клиенту нужен результат выполнения этих запросов, то после выполнения основного запроса(старт очереди) можно реализовать ping сервера и проверять, если очередь отработала - вернуть результат.

Answer (score 0):

Собираем все работающие апи в один массив, а дальше выбираем случайный элемент массива

```
$apis = [ тут доступные апи ];
return $apis[array_rand($apis)];
```